# Nemytskii/superposition operator without separability of Banach space?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis

Let $T:[0,1] \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a nonlinear map where $X$ is a Banach space. Suppose that $T$ is a Caratheodory map, so that $t \mapsto F(t,x)$ is measurable and $x \mapsto F(t,x)$ is continuous. Furthermore suppose that $|F(t,x)| \leq C|x|_X$ holds.

If $X$ is separable, then the superposition map $(Nx)(t) = F(t,x(t))$ is such that $N$ maps $L^p(0,1;X)$ to $L^p(0,1)$.

Let $p \in [1,\infty)$. Now I am wondering, can we remove the need for $X$ to be separable? Every source has mentioned it, but maybe there are better results for this restricted case.